# Android - How to structure a simple Layout

Tags: android

I still dont understand how to use layouts when I'm trying to program for multiple screen sizes. I need to insert an image saying "Facebook" with a distance to the top and the textboxes a bit down.

But if I use margins it will mess up my layout on bigger screen sizes.

**Can someone explain to me the layout of this picture:**

[image: Facebook Login Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by creating layouts for different screen sizes.for that create separate layout folders for different screens and put corresponding layout there.For example

> layout-sw720dp for 720dp devices /
>   layout-sw600dp for 600dp devices

change the dp value according to your need.
you can also make images for different sizes

OR

you can try this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/amna2"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.codeslayers.amnalocations.LoginActivity">




<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/amna" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Van Name"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorHint="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorLink="@color/amna3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"

            android:textColor="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorHint="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorLink="@color/amna3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/district"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Destination"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorHint="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorLink="@color/amna3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dbname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Database Name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorHint="@color/amna3"
            android:textColorLink="@color/amna3" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"

        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/amna4" />/
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that seems like a lot of work. I have 20 different layouts. So i need to create like 100 of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do some thing like this with different dimen.xml (values-sw600dp,values-sw720dp) . So you dont have to duplicate the layout files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inputFields"
        android:id="@+id/facebook_logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/inputFields"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <Button
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Forgot password ?"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signupTxt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Signup for Facebook"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/rotate_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```